# Neo4j internal graph id and transactions

Tags: neo4j, transactions

It is generally not recommended to use the internal Neo4j node IDs.
This is mainly because if a node gets deleted, its original internal
ID may get recycled/reused

Is it safe to use internal Neo4j node IDs in a scope of one transaction ? For example I have started transaction, then found particular node for example by  his name, then I took it's internal Neo4j node ID and use this ID at the rest of the business logic incorporated at the scope of this DB transaction.

Is it safe to use this ID in this case or there is a chance that Neo4j will reuse this internal Neo4j node ID during this transaction lifetime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same transaction it's OK !

Cheers.